# DLookup Crosstab Query from Numeric Field Name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a crosstab with the crosstab value from a Numeric Field, with values of say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

This results in a query with field names that look numeric: i.e. "1", "2", "3", "4", "5".

However, when I do a Dlookup on this query such as:

```
x1 = DLookup("1", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
x2 = DLookup("2", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
x3 = DLookup("3", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
x4 = DLookup("4", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
x5 = DLookup("5", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
```

I just get returns of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 instead of the values in the fields.  This happens even if I do this:

```
x1 = dlookup(1,"aQuery",...)
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Provide example raw data as well as the SQL of the CROSSTAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DLookup

```
x1 = DLookup("1", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
```

is interpreting what you've written as a command to lookup the *value* 1 from your object aQuery.  The result will always be the value you provided in the first argument.

To avoid ambiguity, specify field names with square brackets (still wrap the whole thing in quotes so you can provide it to Dlookup as a string).

```
x1 = DLookup("[1]", "aQuery", "SampleCode ='" & SampleCode & "'")
```

or better still:

```
x1 = DLookup("[1]", "aQuery", "[SampleCode] ='" & [SampleCode] & "'")
```

The brackets are not always necessary, but including them should never create a problem, so it's a good habit to get into when working in Access.